# Page Test results changed page name

Tags: content-testing

I successfully set up a page test achieved the results I wanted and picked a winner based on the stats (Page 1). I then noticed that my original Page 1 name in the content tree was changed to match the Page 2 page name. Does "picking a winner" normally change the page name in the content tree?

thank you